# How to execute a javascript in a Python webdriver

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

Selenium 2 Python webdriver:

I was trying to click on an element which is hidden due to the hover effect and was looking for options to unhide and be able to select the element. To do this, I referred to some examples like below:

In java:

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver();
```

Another example:

```
browser.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('classname').style.display='block'")
```

When I ran the above example, I got the following exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ''
```

I am not sure if I had to include any class for executing the javascript. Please let me know if there is anything iam missing.

Comment: Try to get the actual javascript which that element(which you want to click) runs and then execute it using browser.execute_script. For that you can use something like FireBug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because `getElementsByClassName` returns array of DOM elements. If you need to access first one change your JS to `document.getElementsByClassName('classname')[0].style.display='block'`

Answer (score 2):

I am using below command in python to click on  an element which is hidden

```
element=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Comment: What is `arguments` here?