# How to click on an element based on its coordinates with selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, testing, webdriver

So, the web app we're developing has a TV/PC mode, and i'm testing the ability to transit between these two modes. `

```
 def pc_to_tv(self):
        pc_to_tv = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            'html/body/div[1]/div/topbar/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button[1]')
        pc_to_tv.click()

 def tv_to_pc(self):
      tv_to_pc = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            'html/body/div[1]/div/topbar/header/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/button[2]')
      tv_to_pc.click()`
```

The problem is, when i switch from pc to tv, the screen "zooms in", making the button appear in the same place it would be without the zoom. so, i can't click on the button with my 'tv_to_pc' method, 'cause instead on clicking on the actual button, it clicks where the button should be.

So, the solution i found was clicking on the button with coordinates, that way i'll actually click on the place i want, instead of clicking on an unclickable place like i was doing.

The thing is, i don't know how to do this, and need help on this matter.

Comment: Looks similar to this one: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/8535/selenium-how-to-click-at-x-y-coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just click the button using `JavaScriptExecutor`. It will click it no matter where it is on the page. See [How to execute a javascript in a Python webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303024/how-to-execute-a-javascript-in-a-python-webdriver) and other questions for more info. The general format is

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("someId") 
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Also... you don't want to use XPaths like that. Any XPath that starts at the HTML tag or is more than just a few levels deep is going to be very brittle. Do some googling on selenium xpaths and read some guides for more info.

Answer (score -1):

try moveToElement and then perform click

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element, x, y).click().perform();
```

x is xoffset
y is yoffset

Please see that if you use Javascript for click its not going to be native click.

Comment: That won't work because Selenium already thinks the element is in the wrong place.

Comment: @JeffC I was answering to the question "how to click at co-ordiante", did not pay attention that element was not in view.  you could get the element in view by using following statement before executing the step.  ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);

Comment: That's not the issue either. The issue is that when the browser is zoomed, Selenium misrepresents where the element is on the page and so is missing the click. It's on the page and doesn't need scrolling.

Comment: @jeffc I believe the issue is that element is not in viewport when click happens, Kristhian Aguilar please see if proposed solution works for you.